# Access all images in Assets.xcassets ?? [ SWIFT 3 ]

Tags: ios, swift3

I have some image sets located in Assets.xcassets folder/library, as shown in the screenshot below. All what i want is to add those images to an array so i can use it later on to populate a CollectionView cells. How can i insert those images into an array?

For example, the array should include [airplace.jpg, cars.jpg, ship.jpg]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the way you retrieve an image from the asset catalog is with `UIImage(named:)`. So... How about:

```
let theArray = [UIImage(named:"airplane")!, 
                UIImage(named:"cars")!, 
                UIImage(named:"ship")!]
```

Comment: I could do that but what if i have over 200 images?

Comment: Then you'd still have to do it. If you didn't want to do it that way, you should have put them in a folder. But you didn't. You didn't ask "What would I have to do in order to be able to retrieve the images later without knowing their names one by one?" You presented a specific scenario and asked how to get the images in _that scenario_. And that is what I answered.

Comment: Then how can i use the benefits of @1x, 2x and 3x if i place them in a folder?

Comment: It works fine in a folder. But again: _that is not what you asked_.

Comment: Well, then now i think you know what i really want. Any solution?

Comment: I already told you. You put them in a folder, not in the asset catalog. I do this all the time. No problem.

Comment: by folder you mean creating a new group? or actually creating a folder in the project root?

Comment: Great!, i did exactly what you said. Now how can i loop through the new folder's content into an array?

Comment: Thank you very much man. That is exactly what i was looking for but in swift 2.2 .. i will google it for swift 3.0 version .. appreciate your help :)